# How to show only created record by user who's created it in laravel filament

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

So my object is to show the created record on a filament resource only by the user who created it.

let's say I have a product resource from product model which contains the user_id from user who created it

```
product model
- id
- name
- user_id
```

and let's say we have 2 record on it with different user_id

```
product A
- id = 1
- name = product A
- user_id = 1

product B
- id = 2
- name = product B
- user_id = 2
```

On product resource, I want to show only product that created from specific user (defined by `user_id`) so when the user with user_id = 1 logged in to the system and access the product resource, only the product A is shown in the table

How do I achive that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can customize the resource eloquent query.

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->where('user_id', auth()->id());
}
```

you can also use global scopes.

you can read more from [official docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/getting-started#customizing-the-resource-eloquent-query).

Comment: That works great and shows only the logged-in user in the list. - But how do I jump straight into the View Action for this record and skip the list view completely?

Comment: yes, this will only show the logged-in user data.
I didn't get your second question. You can ask a separate question with more detail.