# I have created Filament Resource called "POINT' How do I show only record created by specific in the filament table

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I want user to see record of things they only added and not see other people record,
Only admin show see all record.

I try filament tenancy but not working for me, I will appreciate any support or reference to documentation that shows example

Comment: Tenancy seems the solution: why it's not working for you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options, but it's mainly just modifying the query that's used.

**First option**

Have a look at this recently asked question: [How to show only created record by user who's created it in laravel filament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535251/how-to-show-only-created-record-by-user-whos-created-it-in-laravel-filament)

You would do something like

```
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->when(!auth()->user()->isAdmin(), fn ($query) => $query->where('user_id', auth()->id()) );
}
```

**Second option**

You could also use the same query for a global scope, filament refers to it in their documentation when you only need a "simple" multi-tenancy, see: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/tenancy#simple-one-to-many-tenancy

**Third option**

Another option would be to add a extra panel, one for the admin and one for the users. Where you still need to change the `getEloquentQuery()` but you won't need the `when()`